# Does the updated Integrated Protection feature of the Warforged mean that they count as "wearing" armor when using armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, armor, warforged

The updated Warforged's [Integrated Protection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/warforged#WarforgedTraits) trait, as detailed in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* (p. 36), now states:

> Your body has built-in defensive layers, which can be enhanced with armor.
>
> - [...]
> - You can don only armor with which you have proficiency. To don armor [...]. To doff armor [...]. You can rest while donning or doffing armor in this way.
> - While you live, your armor can't be removed from your body against your will.

With this revised wording, does the warforged now count as wearing armor when they are using armor in this way?

This is important in the context of how something like integrating a set of plate armor would interact with monk features like Martial Arts.

---

When using a previously published iteration of the Warforged from the initial version of the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* (which one of my players has been using), [there was significant ambiguity over whether or not a warforged was wearing armor](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131728/is-a-warforged-considered-to-be-wearing-armor).
(That version of warforged was identical to [the version in UA: Eberron Races](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf#page=8).)

However, as the most recent iteration of the Warforged (published in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*) has changed this wording so significantly, the question is worth revisiting. (My player also intends to switch to the new published version once they gain a level.)

Comment: Not sure if it changes/meaningfully affects your question, but the wording of this trait did change slightly in the [2020 errata to E:RftLW](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/ERftLW-Errata.pdf): "In the second bullet of Integrated Protection, “To don armor,” has been changed to “To don armor other than a shield,”. Additionally, the third bullet has been changed to read as follows: “While you live, the armor incorporated into your body can’t be removed against your will.”" If it doesn't meaningfully affect the question, you may want to update the quote in the question accordingly.

Comment: ...Oh, and also, the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* was updated as of the the release of *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* - WGtE has been updated on DMsGuild and D&D Beyond (the compendium content) so that the versions of races in that book are identical to E:RftLW. (...That said, I don't think WGtE has been updated (yet) to match the 2020 E:RftLW errata.) I've edited the question to clarify that phrasing a bit; feel free to adjust it as you see fit.

Comment: @V2Blast I'll have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes the warforged counts as wearing armor when they don armor

As noted in the question, the wording now included this point

> - You can don only armor with which you have proficiency. To don armor [...]. To doff armor [...]. You can rest while donning or doffing armor in this way.

With the wording update to explicitly include the phrases don and doff armor, which are defined game terms for getting into and out of armor, the warforged now categorically counts as wearing armor for the purposes of features that make such a distinction.

> Getting Into and Out of Armor
>
> [...]
> **Don.** This is the time it takes to put on the item. You benefit from it's AC only if you take the full time to don it.
>
> **Doff.** This is the time it takes to take off the item. If you have help removing armor, reduce this time by half.

In addition to the above, D&D 5e is an exceptions based game. A creature to be considered to not be wearing armor when they don armor is an exceptional interpretation, and as a result, the game requires an exception to be stated for this to be the case.

Such an exception could take the form:

> the warforged is not considered to be wearing armor after donning it

or

> you gain no benefit from wearing armor

The second of which was part of the reason the previous version of the warforged could be considered to not be wearing armor (and in particular that magical armor wouldn't confer any benefit for them).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116849/discussion-between-illustro-and-makrau).